# NaN in MATLAB while using ratio of power and factorial

Tags: matlab, factorial

In MATLAB, with the following piece of code, I am getting NaN!

```
l=0;
lp=2;
d=200;
a2= ((-sqrt(d))^lp);
a3 =((-sqrt(d))^l);
sum1=0

for m=0:500


a1= ((2^m)*(d^m))/(factorial(m))

mul=a1*a2*a3;
sum1=sum1+mul;
end
```

Is there any way to modify the code to get rid of the issue?

Comment: You're probably getting nan values, as your code runs to enormously large values. You're trying to calculate `2^500 * 200^500 / 500!`. That's got more digits than will fit on my screen. In other words: your problem statement is most likely wrong, as these numbers are impossible to handle for any computer. The outcome may be within bounds, but those intermediate numbers are definitely not. If you can, rewrite your maths in such a way that you don't need things as `500!`

Comment: Work with the *logarithms* of `a1`, `a2` and `a3`; then `mul = exp(log_a1 + log_a2 + log_a3)`

Comment: But the factorial will still cause the trouble

Comment: You should have a look at Stirling's approximation for the factorial and work in logarithms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation
Be extra careful: the logarithm of the sum and the sum of logarithms are not the same thing.

Comment: `factorial(m)` is (mathematically) equivalent to [`gamma(m+1)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gamma.html), so to compute `log(factorial(m))`, you can use [`gammaln(m+1)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gammaln.html).

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out, your intermediate terms are too large so you are getting Inf/Inf resulting in NaN. You could calculate the a1 iteratively inside the loop using the a1 from the previous iteration to avoid this. E.g.,

```
l = 0;
lp = 2;
d = 200; 
d2 = 2 * d; % iteration multiplier
a1 = 1; % value of a1 for first iteration
a2 = ((-sqrt(d))^lp);
a3 = ((-sqrt(d))^l);
sum1 = 0;
for m=0:500
    % a1= ((2^m)*(d^m))/(factorial(m)); % don't use this formulation
    % mul=a1*a2*a3; % don't need a2 and a3 inside loop
    sum1 = sum1 + a1; % add in a1 directly
    a1 = a1 * d2 / (m+1); % calculate a1 for next iteration
end
sum1 = sum1 * a2 * a3 % multiply a2 and a3 at end
```

sum1 = 1.0443e+176

So the calculation can be done in double precision, but this result is a very large number so I would question how you are using this downstream in your code. I.e., are any calculations using this number going to be meaningful? Even a simple calculation such as sum1^2 is going to overflow double precision.

Comment: This is a good approach. But what happens if the function that I need to multiply with a1 depends on 'm'?

Comment: @Jasmine Generally, calculations that depend on m should be inside the loop. If you want more specific advice you will need to show us the function.